# Focus lost when IPleaseWaitService is called before a modal dialog using Catel

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, catel

In summary, I do have a modal dialog in Catel, invoked with:

```
_uiVisualizerService.ShowDialog(viewModel)
```

Inside that dialog, I do a long process showing a Wait Service:

```
_pleasewaitservice.Show();
// HARD WORK here
_pleasewaitservice.Hide();
```

And Then I invoke another modal dialog.

```
_uiVisualizerService.ShowDialog(configureViewModel)
```

However, when I click *outside* of the application while it is doing the *hard work* (when the pleasewaitservice is shown), the second modal dialog is displayed behind the main application, so I cannot focus the Window because it is behind and it is modal. I have to close the app from the task killer.

After checking it carefully, I realized that origin is the pleaseWaitService. If I don't show it, the second modal dialog is always displayed correctly.

Does anyone have any hint about how to solve it?
I was googling about how to force to set focus in any Window, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks

Regards

Saul Hidalgo.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Only difference is that my Window stays visible, but clicking on it does nothing. I have to click on the application in the taskbar first before I can interact with the window. Have you had any luck in resolving your problem?

Comment: Hi, No, I just remove this funtionality...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the BringWindowToTop extension method inside the code-behind of the window:

https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/46fcc69575e533eb9e02669ebaa2246894dc98d8/src/Catel.MVVM/Catel.MVVM.Shared/Windows/Extensions/WindowExtensions.cs#L237

Comment: Hi @geert-van-horrik

I tried it in the following methods of the view: Constructor, OnLoaded, OnLostFocus, EndInit, OnViewModelChanged and OnPropertyChanged, but it didn't work.

I am using it in the following way:

    WindowExtensions.BringWindowToTop(this);

What am I missing? I am sure that Window is loaded because I see it and then it goes behind inmediatly behind the Main Application.